# Java casting to generic

Tags: java

```
public BitMapSet(int[] init){
    for(int n: init) {
        Integer i = new Integer(n);
        if(bitmap.contains(i)){
            System.out.println("There is duplicated value");
        }else{
            bitmap.add(i); //Add individual value into array
        }
    }
}

public void add(T val){
    if(cast(val) < 0 || cast(val) >99){ //range of integers between 0 – 99
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Please enter value between 0 to 99");
    }else{
        if(bitmap[cast(val)]!=1){ //Check for array position exist value
        bitmap[cast(val)]=1; // there is no existing value, change value = 1;
        size++; //increase size
    }
}
```

Error: cannot find symbol method add(java.lang.Integer)

I will like to ask how do i convert the integer type to (T val).. seemed like i need to do up cast which i am very confused.

Kindly correct my understanding if i am wrong.

Thank you

Comment: You have not shown us your declaration of `bitmap`.

Comment: I find it interesting that you've declared the `add(T val)` method argument to be generic, but that you're treating the values as integers all the time, also in the comments! Why not just make it an `add(int val)` method?

Comment: Can you add the missing code?  BitMapSet seems to be a constructor for something, but not a subclass of a set or an implementation of Set, given the bitmap object.  But what is a bitmap object?  You say it is an array in your second code segment, but in the first code segment, you use the contains() method, which is found on classes that implement Collection interface.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, why are you making it generic? Have you tried this...

```
 public void add(int val){
    if(val < 0 || val >99){ //range of integers between 0 – 99
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Please enter value between 0 to 99");
  }else{
    if(bitmap[val]!=1){ //Check for array position exist value
       bitmap[val]=1; // there is no existing value, change value = 1;
       size++; //increase size
  }
}
```

Otherwise if you want to use generics, there is still no need for casting as long as you know that the supplied object will be of a type that can be compared in the manner you have presented.

```
public <T> void add(T val){
    if(val < 0 || val >99){ //range of integers between 0 – 99
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Please enter value between 0 to 99");
  }else{
    if(bitmap[val]!=1){ //Check for array position exist value
       bitmap[val]=1; // there is no existing value, change value = 1;
       size++; //increase size
  }
}
```